# Bluetooth speaker volume control doesn't work (but muting does work)

Tags: bluetooth, pop-os, volume, audio-volume

```
$ neofetch
OS: Pop!_OS 21.10 x86_64 
Kernel: 5.15.8-76051508-generic
```

I have two Bluetooth devices: a speaker `SoundCore Boost` and headphones `EDIFIER W830BT`.

When I'm trying to change the volume on headphones using system volume settings it does work. Headphones also have buttons on them for controlling volume and those buttons also work (they change system volume in Linux).

But on a Bluetooth speaker changing volume in Linux doesn't affect the actual volume. On the other hand, using volume buttons on the speaker does change the system volume in Linux (and the volume level bar in Linux changes as expected when I use the device's buttons).

Also, when I mute system volume in Linux it does affect the speaker (sound mutes).

Summarizing - Bluetooth devices work, sound plays, I can change volumes using devices' buttons but only the speaker volume can't be controlled via Linux system volume (except muting).

I removed and paired again the speaker but that didn't help.

For both devices, `Output Device configuration` is set to `Hight Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)`.

The same speaker works well on macOS (changing system volume affects the speaker volume).

```
$ bluetoothctl devices
Device 00:22:37:59:E0:A5 SoundCore Boost
Device 5C:C6:E9:30:68:EA EDIFIER W830BT
```

```
$ bluetoothctl show
Controller 38:DE:AD:1B:85:90 (public)
    Name: xxxx
    Alias: xxxx
    Class: 0x007c010c
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: no
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
    Pairable: no
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d053C
    Discovering: no
    Roles: central
    Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
    SupportedInstances: 0x05 (5)
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name
```

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

---

Edit 1:

I booted live LTS version with an older kernel

```
$ neofetch
OS: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.13.0-7620-generic
```

And it turned out that there's no issue with that version - system sound control affects the volume of my Bluetooth speaker as expected.

I also booted the live version of my current system (to confirm that there's no issue with my installed version) and the issue with volume control was present.

So my guess is that kernel `5.15.8-76051508-generic` does something with Bluetooth and sound control differently than `5.13.0-7620-generic`.

---

Edit 2:

I downgraded the kernel version to `5.13.0`.
[https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.13/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.13/)

I downloaded 4 files and installed them

```
$ ls
linux-headers-xxx_all.deb
linux-headers-xxx-generic_xxx.deb
linux-image-usigned-xxx-generic_xxx.deb
linux-modules-xxx-generic_xxx.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Pop!_OS doesn't have GRUB and uses `kernelstub`
https://github.com/isantop/kernelstub/blob/master/README.md

I changed the kernel version using the following command (where xxx is the desired kernel version)

```
$ sudo kernelstub -v -k /boot/vmlinuz-xxx-generic -i /boot/initrd.img-xxx-generic
```

After the reboot, I see that I'm using kernel `5.13.0-051300-generic` but that doesn't solve the problem with volume control.

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-051300-generic
```

So my guess is that `Pop!_OS` changed something between `20.04 LTS` and `21.10` that broke proper volume control in my Bluetooth speaker and it's not the kernel's fault.

Comment: Having a similar problem with Ubuntu 22.04. I can change the volume with the buttons on my SoundCore Boost bluetooth speakers and the actual volume setting will be visible on the system, but if I try to change the volume with system controls, it has no effect. Ubuntu 22.04 is using kernel 5.15. Previously I was using Ubuntu 20.04 with and it was different but not better: Bluetooth volume on the system and volume of the device were not linked at all so I had to make sure both were not set too low.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable absolute volume in Pulseaudio's config.

Edit the file

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

And change the line

```
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

to

```
load-module module-bluetooth-discover avrcp_absolute_volume=false
```

---

Credit for this solution goes to https://www.reddit.com/user/mmstick/
https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/s2y0hf/pop_os_2110_brake_bluetooth_device_volume_control/

---

Unfortunately the above solution stopped working for me (kernel `5.19.0-76051900-generic`)
But I found another solution that works for me currently: https://askubuntu.com/a/1350436